# In an XPiNC app, how can I launch one XPage vs. another based on Role

Tags: xpages, xpinc

I have an XPiNC app that consists of two different XPages. The XPages are set up to be used based on Roles. One Role is for the people who set up the content and the other is for those that consume it.

One of my requirements is that the Consumer Role wants to open the NSF from the desktop and have it automatically open the Consumer XPage. I know I can set the Launch property to do this for the Consumers, but that also causes the Content Providers to open that XPage which is not what should happen.

How can I set it up so that the application opens to the proper XPage based on their Role?

Comment: Sounds like you need a disambiguation. My gut says maybe this is possible using an XAgent but I'm not certain. I'd try setting up an XAgent, setting that as your Launch property, and in the AfterRenderResponse, navigating to the proper XPage based on role. Information on XAgents can be found here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7mgfbn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to have a third page which is the launch page. This page would just have a beforePageLoads event that looks at the user roles and then does a `context.redirectToPage("/otherpage.xsp")` depending on the role detected.

Comment: This was the perfect solution and only took a few lines of code. Get the Role, test for each possibility and open the correct page based on the results.

Comment: One more suggestion. On the other pages you should do the reverse. Check to see if the person has the role for that particular page, if they don't send them back to the launch page. This way if somebody emails the url of one of the pages to somebody without the role they can't get into it.

Comment: Thanks Dec. I redid the entire app over the weekend to get it to work on one XPage instead of requiring two.

Answer (score 4):

The Include Page component (`<xp:include />`) supports a `pageName` attribute which can be computed. If you set your launch page to an XPage that consists only of a `<xp:include />`, and compute `pageName` based on user roles (e.g. `context.getUser().getRoles().contains("[Consumer]") ? "/consumer.xsp" : "/index.xsp"`), then what the user actually sees will be role-dependent.

Comment: Tim, I am unfamiliar with the include option. Are you saying that I could have one XPage and have it open either of the other XPages based on the role on the same page?

Comment: Roy, that's correct: the `include` component essentially embeds one page inside another, but in a server state sense, not like an `iframe`. In a way, it's just like adding any Custom Control to an XPage, but with two key differences: you're embedding an entire XPage inside the other XPage, not just a Custom Control, and you can compute *which* page is included, instead of having to know at design-time which content you want in that location within the component tree.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but for my benefit. Would you be able to have 1 xpage and then load a custom control dynamically based on the role?